# How can I check for non-threadsafe code?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, multithreading, rubygems, thread-safety

I am using **Rails 3.2** and **Ruby 1.9.3**. I want to use with ***puma server*** with `config.threadsafe!` in `production env`  but before going with `threadsafe`  I want to ensure my application will not break. How can I check my codebase for code that is not thread-safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automatic way to do this. I would write a spec/test for each code block that accesses shared resources - global variables and resources that should be modified with an exclusive lock.

If you find yourself suspecting too much code then there are 2 options:

1. You're doing something wrong and leading to concurrency with no good reason. Refactor ASAP!
2. You're explicitly specifying in your tests that the code under test is designed and tested for concurrency.

Which is a win-win.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Would be great if there were though. Sorry. :(